# How to turn of panorama effect in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

My computer lags pretty hard when it does that zoom in and zoom out.
Is it like possible to turn off the zoom effect in panorama?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [disable animations in Firefox Panorama](http://techdows.com/2011/01/disable-panorama-or-tab-groups-animations.html) with this procedure:

1. Type about:config into the address bar and agree to the warning.
2. Locate the browser.panorama.animate_zoom entry, double click it, and set its value to `false`